# io.vertx.core.eventbus.ReplyException: Timed out after waiting 30000(ms) for a reply. address: 4, repliedAddress: getMethodToOtherService

Tags: timeout, vert.x

I'm getting the timeout error when the response from the other service is exceeding 30 seconds, How can I increase the timeout to 60 seconds in vertX if the response from other service is delayed. In my case the response is taking 34 seconds.

```
io.vertx.core.eventbus.ReplyException: Timed out after waiting 30000(ms) for a reply. address: 4, repliedAddress: getMethodToOtherService
    at io.vertx.core.eventbus.impl.HandlerRegistration.sendAsyncResultFailure(HandlerRegistration.java:127) ~[vertx-core-3.5.4.jar:3.5.4]
    at io.vertx.core.eventbus.impl.HandlerRegistration.lambda$new$0(HandlerRegistration.java:78) ~[vertx-core-3.5.4.jar:3.5.4]
    at io.vertx.core.impl.VertxImpl$InternalTimerHandler.handle(VertxImpl.java:885) ~[vertx-core-3.5.4.jar:3.5.4]
    at io.vertx.core.impl.VertxImpl$InternalTimerHandler.handle(VertxImpl.java:844) ~[vertx-core-3.5.4.jar:3.5.4]
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.lambda$wrapTask$2(ContextImpl.java:339) ~[vertx-core-3.5.4.jar:3.5.4]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163) [netty-common-4.1.19.Final.jar:4.1.19.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:404) [netty-common-4.1.19.Final.jar:4.1.19.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:463) [netty-transport-4.1.19.Final.jar:4.1.19.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:886) [netty-common-4.1.19.Final.jar:4.1.19.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) [netty-common-4.1.19.Final.jar:4.1.19.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_211]
2023-07-20T13:12:11,670 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-1] INFO  com.github.phiz71.vertx.swagger.router.SwaggerRouter - -1 is not a valid HttpStatusCode
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: code: -1 (expected: 0+)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpResponseStatus.<init>(HttpResponseStatus.java:581) ~[netty-codec-http-4.1.19.Final.jar:4.1.19.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpResponseStatus.<init>(HttpResponseStatus.java:569) ~[netty-codec-http-4.1.19.Final.jar:4.1.19.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpResponseStatus.valueOf(HttpResponseStatus.java:446) ~[netty-codec-http-4.1.19.Final.jar:4.1.19.Final]
    at com.github.phiz71.vertx.swagger.router.SwaggerRouter.isExistingHttStatusCode(SwaggerRouter.java:254) ~[vertx-swagger-router-1.6.1.TK-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at com.github.phiz71.vertx.swagger.router.SwaggerRouter.manageError(SwaggerRouter.java:241) ~[vertx-swagger-router-1.6.1.TK-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at com.github.phiz71.vertx.swagger.router.SwaggerRouter.lambda$null$10(SwaggerRouter.java:167) ~[vertx-swagger-router-1.6.1.TK-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at io.vertx.core.eventbus.impl.HandlerRegistration.sendAsyncResultFailure(HandlerRegistration.java:127) ~[vertx-core-3.5.4.jar:3.5.4]
    at io.vertx.core.eventbus.impl.HandlerRegistration.lambda$new$0(HandlerRegistration.java:78) ~[vertx-core-3.5.4.jar:3.5.4]
    at io.vertx.core.impl.VertxImpl$InternalTimerHandler.handle(VertxImpl.java:885) ~[vertx-core-3.5.4.jar:3.5.4]
    at io.vertx.core.impl.VertxImpl$InternalTimerHandler.handle(VertxImpl.java:844) ~[vertx-core-3.5.4.jar:3.5.4]
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.lambda$wrapTask$2(ContextImpl.java:339) ~[vertx-core-3.5.4.jar:3.5.4]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163) [netty-common-4.1.19.Final.jar:4.1.19.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:404) [netty-common-4.1.19.Final.jar:4.1.19.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:463) [netty-transport-4.1.19.Final.jar:4.1.19.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:886) [netty-common-4.1.19.Final.jar:4.1.19.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) [netty-common-4.1.19.Final.jar:4.1.19.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_211]
```

I have tried with the below approaches to increase the timeout in my vertX project.

**Approach 1 : **
`long TIMEOUT_IN_MS = 60000L; SessionStore store = LocalSessionStore.create(vertx); router.route() .handler(SessionHandler.create(store).setSessionTimeout(TIMEOUT_IN_MS))`

**Approach 2 : **
`vertx.setTimer(60000, id -> {//vertx deployment here}); Setting the timer to vertex object`

**Approach 3 :**
`EventBusOptions eventBusOptions = new EventBusOptions(); eventBusOptions.setConnectTimeout(60000); vertxOptions.setEventBusOptions(eventBusOptions); vertx = Vertx.vertx(vertxOptions);`

Please suggest if there is any other way around.

Answer (score 0):

You can [change the timeout](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_sending_with_timeouts) using `DeliveryOptions`:

```
Future<Message<Object>> request = eb.request(ADDRESS1, str, new DeliveryOptions().setSendTimeout(timeout));
```